# GNU Emacs for Windows ignores PATH for scripts only

Tags: windows, bash, emacs, cygwin

I like to use cygwin bash with the FSF port of GNU Emacs (not to be confused with the cygwin port of GNU Emacs) on windows 10. My .emacs defines shell-file-name to be cygwin bash. When I use the emacs compile command, or the emacs asynch shell command with an executable that is in my PATH environment variable, there is no problem.

However, when I use my home grown sql-client.pl script with the compile command,

1. `$USERPROFILE/Documents/bin/sql-client.pl` works fine
2. `sql-client.pl` (note no directory path) gives me the error `Can't open perl script "/cygdrive/c/Users/shein/Documents/bin/sql-client.pl": No such file or directory` even though the bin directory is in my path. Clearly, cygwin bash found it but won't execute it!

However, at the eval prompt the following lisp code works fine:

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*") (call-process *bash* nil (current-buffer) nil "-c" "sql-client.pl"))
```

(Note that it finds sql-client.pl in the PATH without me having to specify the path to the script).

I get similar results with the groovy (a bash script) command: if I specify the full path at the compile command, it works. If I use the "call-process" function from elisp, it works. However it cannot (does not) execute it from the compile command without the path. It finds it, but, like sql-client.pl, cygwin bash won't execute it.

Using the cygwin `chmod u+x groovy` or `chmod u+x sql-client.pl` command does not help.

But if I use groovy.bat instead of groovy and don't specify a path, it works!

Or, if I use the console bash prompt, everything works.

Is this a bug in emacs or cywgin bash? One workaround is to always specify a path for my scripts but this can be cumbersome...  Does anyone have another nicer workaround?

Thanks

Siegfried

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using the Cygwin port of Emacs, I don't see why Emacs should invoke bash unless you explicitly say so. Assuming that you also have a Windows port of Perl installed (such as Active State Perl), I would call your script explicitly via `perl -x sql-client.pl`.

Note also that the executable rights simulated by Cygwin don't have much meaning in the Windows world anyway, so I guess they don't matter anyway, unless you run the program via some Cygwin shell.

Comment: I use Active State or Strawberry or Cygwin perl depending on the script (in this example, I need to use 32 bit strawberry perl because I'm manipulating a 32 bit MS Access databases). I use the bash she-bang syntax to invoke the correct perl for that script. Strawberry perl is deliberately not in my PATH. So explicitly specifying the full path to the appropriate perl is a burden...Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh yes -- the emacs compile command invokes cygwin bash because I set shell-file-name in my .emacs...  My windows Emacs compile command can also invoke windows powershell or linux powershell or ubuntu bash too via WSL2...

Comment: @user3477493 : Does an explicit  `perl -x ...` work,?

Comment: @user3477493 : You said that you can invoke *Ubuntu* bash in this way. I find it confusing that you try tor run two very different "bash-worlds" in parallel (WSL, Cygwin). Can you invoke a bash script directly with Cygwin bash (i.e. not relying on Ubuntu)? If this is the case, I would write a bash wrapper script, which only invokes your `sql-client.pl`. Even if it still fails to run it, we have at least a well-defined environment, which we can debug.

Comment: Yes, I can invoke perl & bash scripts directly in cygwin bash without ubuntu bash and vice versa. But as I mentioned originally, I'm having the identical problem with cygwin bash scripts (like the bash "groovy" script that invokes the groovy interpreter/compiler) as I am with perl scripts: the emacs compile command correctly finds them by using the $PATH and then won't execute them. As I explained above, when I use the emacs elisp call-process function, it correctly uses the $PATH to find the bash script and successfully executes (calls) the script.

Comment: user3477493: Just using "perl" works but requires I memorize which perl to use (see above) and does not help with cygwin bash scripts.

Comment: @user3477493 : My guess is that Emacs tries to run the programs without using a shell, just by looking at the PATH, and since it is a Windows-port of Emacs, even if it tries to make sense of the `#!` line in the scripts - and it is not clear whether Emacs is doing it - these denote pathes in the Cygwin world (such as `/usr/bin`), which don't exist in Windows. I don't know whether Emacs has a switch to **force** using the shell for executing a command. Maybe this would be worth researching.